# When can the Rust compiler not prove that borrows are disjoint?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In [section 3.2 of the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/references.html#liveness), under the heading "liveness", it says

> However it's often the case that Rust isn't sufficiently smart to
>   prove that  multiple borrows are disjoint.

What is an example where the Rust compiler cannot prove that they are disjoint? Will this ever occur in a tuple struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is in the previous sentence:

> Rust explicitly enables [reborrowing into multiple mutable references] to be done with disjoint struct fields, because disjointness can be statically proven

Outside of this case, the compiler cannot tell that two borrows are disjoint. In practice, this means that the compiler cannot tell that borrows resulting from a function call will be disjoint.

```
struct Thing {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}
```

```
fn example_works(thing: &mut Thing) {
    let a = &mut thing.a;
    let b = &mut thing.b;
}
```

```
fn get_a(thing: &mut Thing) -> &mut i32 {
    &mut thing.a
}

fn get_b(thing: &mut Thing) -> &mut i32 {
    &mut thing.b
}

fn example_doesnt_work(thing: &mut Thing) {
    let a = get_a(thing);
    let b = get_b(thing);
    println!("{}, {}", a, b);
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*thing` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:26:19
   |
25 |     let a = get_a(thing);
   |                   ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
26 |     let b = get_b(thing); // cannot borrow `*thing` as mutable more than once at a time
   |                   ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
27 |     println!("{}, {}", a, b);
   |                        - first borrow later used here
```

> Will this ever occur in a tuple struct?

Not specifically *because* it's a tuple struct, but yes, it can happen for the same reasons. If you obtain a borrow from a function call, you will get the same problem as a "traditional" struct.